# Passing string from binvar to a file

Tags: mirc

How can i write binvar to a file with line breaks?

```
noop $hget(row, siirMisralari_txt, &binvar)
fopen poemFile temp_text.txt
fwrite -bn poemFile &binvar
fclose poemFile
bunset &binvar
```

This code can t include line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

```
bwrite temp_text.txt 0 $hget(row, siirMisralari_txt, &binvar) &binvar
```

Comment: i just noticed it. windows notepad can t show line feeds but notepad++ does.

Comment: if it's just `$lf` then yea, you can't open it in notepad. But `$crlf` will. Wordpad will do fine for either I believe.

Answer (score -1):

That's the fantastic of binary! It can contain any binary values! Your line breaks must be lost before adding the binary data to the hash table. You need `/hadd -b` if you're working with binvars there.
You can `/echo -a $bvar(&binvar,1-)` and search for the line breaks depending on what format the file had/has.
 Unix: LF ($chr(10)), Win: CRLF ($+($chr(13),$chr(10))), Mac: CR ($chr(13)).

Comment: thanks for the answer. i want to make it clear. i m trying to get data from sqlite database and send lines to irc server. how can i save all lines of a long text to a file with line breaks? i don't know much about hash tables and i doubt if it s necessary. this code: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/43813/ can t keep utf8 format.